# Is it possible to code a generic DEMUX (1 input, multiple outputs) in VHDL?

Tags: generics, vhdl

My FPGA software has a drag and drop feature to developing elements or system design. It works best with "generic" components that allows the user to set the modifiable parameters without having to go into the code and change things. To that end I decided to create a generic demuxer with one input and multiple outputs. The design must allow the user to define the number of outputs and the bitwidth of the input and output ports (both are same width). The design also has to determine the bitwidth of the output select port depending upon the number of output ports selected (that part I have taken care of with a function). Please note that due to my limitations the number of output ports can be between 2 and 256 outputs. Is it possible to code for variable number of outputs in a design or is it a pipe dream. Please note that I have written code for many fixed output demuxes.

Comment: The normal way to ask a question like this would be to include an example of what you have tried, with an explanation of what has gone wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I perfectly understood what you were looking for, but I'll try to answer correctly.

First of all it depends if your tool support VHDL-2008 or not. Many customizable features are unavailable in VHDL-1993.

If you do this can probably work:

You first need to define a type in a package `your_package.vhdl`

```
TYPE    demux_output    IS ARRAY (natural range <>) OF  std_logic_vector;
```

Then you can define your entity as follow :

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE WORK.your_package.ALL;

ENTITY demux IS
    GENERIC (PORT_WIDTH : integer := 8; -- define your data width
            NB_OUTPUT : integer := 50); -- define the number of outputs needed

    PORT    (input      : IN std_logic_vector(PORT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
            output      : OUT demux_output(0 TO NB_OUTPUT - 1)(PORT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
            sel         : IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0));

END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE RTL OF demux IS

SIGNAL sel_int  : integer := 0;

BEGIN

sel_int <= to_integer(unsigned(sel));

PROCESS (sel_int, input)
BEGIN
    output <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0'));
    FOR i IN 0 TO (NB_OUTPUT - 1) LOOP
        IF (i = sel_int) THEN
            output(i) <= input;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END PROCESS;

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

There, you only need to declare the width of your ports (`PORT_WIDTH`) and the number of output ports (`NB_OUTPUT`).

If your tool isn't compliant with VHDL-2008 you won't be able to declare an unconstrained data width in the type `demux_output`. That's why you'll have to define a global constant, but this would probably lose the "customizable part" that you're looking for.

Comment: If your tool has VHDL2008 support, you could use a type generic instead of involving a package.

Comment: True, but I find it lacks of "sexyness" :p

Comment: Finally got time to really go over the code and fully understand what you suggested. You almost got it correct. In the example you gave to have the input being directed to a location in an array but not actual output ports. My goal was to have the input be connected to specific outputs and the data latched at that output. I thought of using an array but decided it was not what I was looking for as it then required me to develop another entity that accessed the array and routed it to a unique output. It is appearing that I will not be able to make the number of  outputs a generic feature.

Answer (score 0):

To A.K and scary_jeff, thanks for the response. I will check with my tool to see if it is compliant with VHDL-2008. Just so you know, I am very new to VHDL and learning quickly but it doesn't take long for me to get into more complicated designs that I end up trying to make as simple as possible. The are a couple of lines that I sort of follow but are new to me such as;

output      : OUT demux_output(0 TO NB_OUTPUT - 1)(PORT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);

While I understand what it is saying, in all of the research I have done none of it showed a capability or an example like it. The other line;

output <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0'));

Again I have never seen any documentation on the keyword "others" so the line doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain or maybe let me know of a "good" VHDL resource I can use. That way instead of asking newbie type questions I can ask for help on more complex issues. Again, thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  SO is not a discussion forum.  If you want clarification on an answer add a comment to the specific answer.  You should delete this.